# Crash happening when using removeObjectsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:]

Tags: objective-c

self.filteredProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
    //Find products
    self.filteredProducts = (NSMutableArray*)[(NSMutableDictionary *)[self.CECategoriesDictionary objectForKey:category.categoryGuid] allValues];

    if([self.oldfilteredProducts count] > 0 && selectedLevel==5)
    {
        NSMutableArray *diff = [self.filteredProducts mutableCopy];
        [diff removeObjectsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.oldfilteredProducts]];
        [self.filteredProducts removeObjectsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:diff]];
    }
```

Logs :

[__NSArrayI removeObjectsInArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1aed19d0
2014-09-15 22:00:19.243 SAPRetailEx[10325:90b] [ERROR]:Uncaught exception: -[__NSArrayI removeObjectsInArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1aed19d0
2014-09-15 22:00:19.243 SAPRetailEx[10325:90b] [ERROR]:-[__NSArrayI removeObjectsInArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1aed19d0
2014-09-15 22:00:19.248 SAPRetailEx[10325:90b] [ERROR]:(

Comment: You might want to try using the debugger to check what the object type of `diff` is after it's been set. It must be `NSMutableArray` for this to work. Also, you don't need to use `NSArray arrayWithArray:` when calling `removeObjectsInArray:`. You're just wasting CPU and RAM to create an array you don't need.

Comment: You can't mutate an immutable object.  (This is what the exception message was clearly telling you.)

Answer (score 5):

you cannot remove objects form `NSArray`; I know you think you are using an `NSMutableArray` but you are not. This is made quite clear from your error `[__NSArrayI removeObjectsInArray:]: unrecognized selector`; `__NSArrayI` is an immutable object (that is what the `I` means), if this were really a mutable array the class would be `__NSArrayM`.

you seem to be operating under the false impression that you can get a mutable array simply by casting an `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`; this has *never* been how casting works under any C derived language. You instead need to send a `mutableCopy` message to the `NSArray`. Of course you now have a *copy* of the array so modifications arent reflected in the original. you also own the copy so if you arent using ARC you need to `release` the copy when you are done.

I'm curious to know why you are already making a `mutableCopy` of `self.filteredProducts` then also trying to remove directly from `self.filteredProducts`. even if this worked how you expect you are now copying the array for no reason then removing from both thee "original" and the "copy".

Comment: how can i convert self self.filteredProducts to NSMutableArray so that i can remove object from it which are same in diff array as i need it.

Comment: @NehitGurubaxani you need to declare self.filteredProducts as an `NSMutableArray` then where you are assigning an `NSArray` to it you instead do `self.filteredProducts` = [theArray mutableCopy]`. However, looking at your code that will be the same as `diff` so I dont know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`self.filteredProducts` isn't really an `NSMutableArray` It's just a normal `NSArray` which doesn't have a "remove option".

`[self.filteredProducts removeObjectsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:diff]`

To help in the future... set at break point in your code after you assign it, then print out the description and see what type of object it really is. either `po` in the debugger or right click on "Print Description". Don't believe what is says on the left panel, that's just what you told the code the object is, look at the description on the right to see what it really is.

[image]